# How can I scale a quad by its X axis rather than my point of view?

Tags: modeling, scale

How can I scale a quad by its X axis rather than my point of view? 
[image: Here is the Image]

Comment: For a general solution In 2.79, select an edge or 2 verts defining the direction of scale, create a Custom Orientation from them (Ctrl-Alt-Space), check 'Use after creation', and SYY.

Answer (score 1):

Choose normal as transformation oriention.
[image]

Comment: Thank you.. I'll give that a try. 
I'll come back should it not solve it.
EDIT: Thank you.. this solved it. 
Now pressing two times any axis does work! <3